# button getLeft() and getTop() returning 0

Tags: android

I have an issue with the getLeft() and getTop(), it is returning 0. I saw on Stackoverflow I should use GlobaleLayoutListener but still not working.

My view is working in this way. There is a first horizontal scrollview bar to let the user selects the period the user wants to see his chart. And when he selects "Weekly" or "Monthly" a second bar shows up. The user can select a month or a day. So at the beginning the second bar is in visibility gone.

I want to set the item of the second bar. Because like today we are in September, I want the first item for the second bar to be September if the user clicks on Monthly.

I tried that:

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = decButton.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            System.out.println("KIRBY " + decButton.getLeft());
            //in here, place the code that requires you to know the dimensions.
            //Place your code here
        }
    });
```

But it is not working :/

There is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</RelativeLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/quickViewConsumptionToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/wb_color"
    android:titleTextColor="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/toolbar_white"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/hello">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/test">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100px">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/dailyButton"
                        android:text="Daily"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/weeklyButton"
                        android:text="Weekly"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/monthlyButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="Monthly"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/yearlyButton"
                        android:text="Yearly"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/allTimeButton"
                        android:text="All time"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalBar"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5px"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalMonthlyBarBellow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/janButton"
                        android:text="January"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/febButton"
                        android:text="February"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/marchButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="March"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/aprilButton"
                        android:text="April"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/mayButton"
                        android:text="May"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/juneButton"
                        android:text="June"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/julyButton"
                        android:text="July"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/augButton"
                        android:text="August"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/septView"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/sepButton"
                        android:text="September"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/octButton"
                        android:text="October"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/novButton"
                        android:text="November"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/decButton"
                        android:text="December"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalBarWeeklyBellow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/mondayButton"
                        android:text="Monday"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/tuesdayButton"
                        android:text="Tuesday"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/wednesdayButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="Wednesday"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/thursdayButton"
                        android:text="Thursday"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/fridayButton"
                        android:text="Friday"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/saturdayButton"
                        android:text="Saturday"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/sundayButton"
                        android:text="Sunday"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view_wb_quick_view_consumption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400px"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/test"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`View` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), discussing methods to retrieve position:

> These methods both return the location of the view relative to its parent. For instance, when `getLeft()` returns 20, that means the view is located 20 pixels to the right of the left edge of its direct parent.

The reason that the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` technique "isn't working" for you is that your `decButton` is wrapped in a `RelativeLayout` with no spacing (margins/padding) from that `RelativeLayout`'s top-left corner.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/decButton"
        android:text="December"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

To get the absolute position of your `Button` in the window, use this code inside your `OnGlobalLayoutListener`:

```
int[] coords = new int[2];
decButton.getLocationInWindow(coords);
int absoluteX = coords[0];
int absoluteY = coords[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the methods are being called before the view has been measured. I don't know how `GlobalLayoutListener` works. Instead, you could try the following code to get it working for you if nothing else works

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        decButton.getLeft()    // This method will run after 200ms.
    }
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the view may not have been inflated by the time you query for the X position of the view. You can try something like this.

```
decButton.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        float leftX = decButton.getLeft();
        float topY = decButoon.getTop();
        System.out.println(leftX + " " + topY);
    }
});
```

Also if you try to get location of a view while the view or its any ascendant parents is gone, you will get 0.